# What time are you in for the TRE?

Tags: discussion, retagging, chat-event

*Follow up of [Throw in an idea for TRE (II)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3113/throw-in-an-idea-for-tre-ii), and taking the advice in the answers into account, and coming up with an optimal time for TRE.*

Please write an answer to declare that you'd like to participate in the event. Please issue three time ranges:

- ### The Optimal Time Range:

  Hours of the days you'd like to participate in our chat event. Ideally, this won't affect your private life scheduling thingy.
- ### The Sub-optimal Time Range:

  Hours of the days you may be able to participate, but might need to change some timelines and schedules and all that stuff, assuming you can. Dud(in)e, it's called sub-optimal for a reason.
- ### Mission Impossible

  After the other answers come up, I'd also appreciate it if you include that whether any time range in the other answers is a no-no: You can't participate in TRE at the time the other answer(s) mentioned.

**Addendum**: If you see that your schedule is much like one of the answers and thus *your* answer will be redundant, post a comment under the answer saying that you're okay with the time range in the answer. This is necessary because I want to have a crude idea of how many people will participate.

Thank you.

Comment: My lack of activity on the site reflects the fact that I'm unfortunately much busier this year. :( If you all fix a time, I may or may not drop in for a short while to help out, mostly by editing formatting and stuff like that (because I find that easy), but don't count on that.

Comment: Basically any evening/late afternoon (UTC) would be probably OK for me, especially on weekends.

Comment: Basically I have the same scheme as Mithoron.

Comment: Sadly, I feel good atm with how much I cut down my SE usage, so I likely won’t be participating. Maybe when my thesis is handed in and defended …

Comment: Best of luck @Jan! I'm pretty sure a good strategy of thesis defense is flipping a periodic table.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, here's my schedule (in UTC):

\begin{array}{llcr}
\text{day}                & \text{sub-}& \text{opt. time} &\text{sub-} \\\hline
\text{Monday}             & 2:00 \sim  & 3:00 - 15:00     & \sim 17:00 \\
\text{Tuesday - Thursday} & 1:00 \sim  & 3:00 - 15:00     & \sim 17:00 \\
\text{Friday}             & 1:00 \sim  & 3:00 - 13:00     & \sim 14:00 \\   
\text{Saturday, Sunday}   & \hfill\sim & \Large\color{red}{\text{ಠ_ಠ}} 
                                                          &\sim\hfill  \\\hline
\end{array}

Comment: It's official. We'll hold TRE on a peaceful Saturday afternoon. :P

Answer (score 4):

### The Optimal Time Range:

My schedule is a bit relaxed, so I can give y'all some wide choice. (Time is UTC)

\begin{array}{cc}
{\bf \large Day} & {\bf \large Opt. time} \\\hline
\rm \small MON & 11:30-14:30~\&~18:30-20:30\\
\rm \small TUE & 10:00-13:30~\&~15:30-18:30\\
\rm \small WED & 10:00-18:30\\
\rm \small THU & 7:00-11:30\\
\rm \small FRI & 8:30-18:30\\
\rm \small SAT & 15:00-18:30\\
\rm \small SUN & 10:00-13:30~\&~15:30-18:30\\
\end{array}

### The Sub-optimal Time Range:

[image]

On second thought, I think I can stretch my time a bit and fill the gaps on Sunday and Tuesday, but I really rather not to.

<sub><sub><sub>Pic source: http://static1.1.sqspcdn.com/static/f/346753/16351957/1328084130240/empty+desert.jpg?token=oPzeG1RFBhouWx0CKyhH%2FRIc%2FiY%3D</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: This strange Iranian time zone ;)

Comment: I'm okay which some of the timeline cause is night to me. But I might post some of my opt time

Answer (score 3):

**The Optimal Time Range:**

My time is stressed this year cause I'm in the last year of high school.So, these are my opt. time range (in UTC)

- Monday until Friday: 12:30-14:30
- Saturday: Basically free from 6:30-14:30 (But not next Saturday cause I'm busy)
- Sunday: Basically free from 8:00-14:30

**The Sub-optimal Time Range:**

I have some tutoring work to do after the time below. But sometime I will be earlier to do some preparation so I will say it's sub-optimal.

- Monday & Tuesday: 8:00-10:00
- Wednesday & Friday: 7:30-8:30